# Output with and without parenthesis

Tags: c#

```
int fahrenheit = 94;

decimal celsius = ( fahrenheit - 32m ) * (5m / 9m) ;

Console.WriteLine(celsius);
```

If I compile this code the output is 34.444444444444444444444444447

But if I don't use a parenthesis at the expression 5m / 9m the output is 34.444444444444444444444444444
Why?

Can somebody explain what is going on here?

Comment: Operator precedence of * and / over + and -.

Comment: `decimal` is useful but still has limited precision. If you're performing operations in different orders, the limited precision of the intermediate results can affect the result.

Comment: It is a rounding error due to 320/9 giving a different rounding error than 5/9.  320 is 5 *(94 - 32)

Comment: Also, beware of spurious accuracy. Your inputs, considered together, have 0 decimal places of accuracy. You really shouldn't be concerned or showing 27 digits in the result and worrying over the last digit.

Answer (score 0):

if you use parenthesis
first `(94 - 32m) = 62m` will be counted

second `(5m / 9m) = 0.5555555555555555555555555556`will be counted
after that

`firstResult * secondResult = 34.444444444444444444444444447` will be counted

but Without parenthesis

first `(94 - 32m) = 62m` will be counted

second `firstResult * 5m = 310` will be counted

then `secondResult / 9m = 34.444444444444444444444444444` will be counted

Answer (score 0):

Floats are floats because precision basically jumps between two closest points which data type can represent. Its floating in a sea of variants. Each time you perform something, you have a chance of loosing some precision.

In your case, its lost precision on order of execution.

Short rule of thumb for getting max available precision (usually this approach used in multiplication of sparse matrix) - try to combine `* /` operands in such way that result become closer to values with small power of two (closer to center of float), then at the end of calculation you can perform unprecise operations, leaving single point of loosing precision. This will usually leave you with average best results.

Important to note is that **float density** becomes smaller when number is bigger or too small. In other words:

1. Same number of available floats for each [2^N, 2^(N+1)] interval
2. Floating error, becomes (2^(N+1) - 2^N)/(2^23) which obviously becomes bigger when N is too large or too small.
3. Operations on really big floats are less precise
4. Operations on really small floats are less precise
5. Operations on floats of N=0 are most precise (and usually around N=[-10,10])

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's the decimal point that "floats" and gives a `float` its name

Comment: I tend to explain it like this, because it is more understandable. Usually.